# How do I only click a button if it contains a specific word

Tags: javascript, if-statement, firefox, imacros

I'm trying to click a button if it contains a specific word. I'm not sure how to even store the word and check if the button has the specific word or not. Could I please get some help.

So in this case, if the button in a specific POS (which is changing in the while loop. The position is defined by `i`) says `Accept Request`, I want to play the `add_to_group` macro.

---

**In depth explanation:**

1. Enter's the while loop. The button is position `POS=1`
2. The if statement must check if the button in `POS=1` says `Accept Request`.
3. If the button says `Accept Request`, it plays the `add_to_group` macro
4. `i++`
5. The button is position `POS=2`
6. The if statement must check if the button in `POS=2` says `Accept Request`.
7. If the button says `Accept Request`, it plays the `add_to_group` macro
8. `i++`
9. And so on...

---

**How the page looks:**

```
Username1               [Accept Request] // This is POS=1
Username2               [Accept Request] // This is POS=2
Username3               [Already Added!] // This is POS=3
Username4               [Accept Request] // This is POS=4
Username5               [Already Added!] // This is POS=5
Username6               [Request Denied] // This is POS=6
```

---

**my imacro.js:**

```
var add_to_group;
add_friend = "CODE:";
add_friend += "SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1" + "\n";
add_friend += "TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Accept<SP>Request" + "\n";


var i = 1;
while (i < 7) {

    if (if the button says 'Accept Request' then click it") { // This is where I don't know what to put

        iimSet("i", i);
        // Clicks the button
        iimPlay(add_to_group);
    }

    i++;
}
```

Comment: `buttonText.contains("Accept Request")` ?

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev But how do I check that its checking this: `TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Accept<SP>Request` and not just in general?

Comment: `add_friends.contains(...)` ? I really don't understand what you are looking for. I also don't understand what that uppercase text is supposed to be.

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev Edited my post to explain it better.

Comment: What you are doing makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev What makes no sense? I don't want to click the button that says `Already Added!`. All the buttons are in different positions. Each time I go through the loop, it checks if that button says `Accept Request`